# Are there any common field names for the FGDC street address standard fields?

Tags: standards, address, fields-attributes

I have been looking into implementing the [FGDC street address data standards](http://www.fgdc.gov/standards/projects/FGDC-standards-projects/street-address/05-11.2ndDraft.CompleteDoc.pdf) so that my address data is potentially consistent with other US data I obtain in the future. However, the FGDC documentation doesn't suggest actual names to name the fields.

I currently am using the following fields:

```
555 1 SW Main St, Ste B

 - ST_NUMBR:  555
 - ST_NSFX:   1
 - ST_PREFIX: SW
 - ST_PRETYPE:
 - ST_NAME:   Main
 - ST_TYPE:   ST
 - ST_POSTDIR:
 - ST_UNIT:   Ste B
```

To be consistent, I should probably change the `ST_PREFIX` field to `ST_PREDIR`, but if I'm making changes I might as well know if there are other conventions I should be following.

Are there any standard or common names for such address fields?